# discord.js v13 Interaction button delete orginal message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```js
const row = new Discord.MessageActionRow()
  .addComponents(
    new Discord.MessageButton()
      .setCustomId(`deletable`)
      .setLabel('❌')
      .setStyle(4)
  );

user.send({content: 'hi', components: [row]});
```

When the button is clicked:

```js
client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', async (interaction) => {
  const {
    data: {
      custom_id
    }
  } = interation;

  if (custom_id && custom_id === "deletable") {
    let channel = await client.messages.fetch({
      around: interaction.message.id,
      limit: 1
    }).then((msg) => {
      const fetchedMsg = msg.first();
      console.log(msg);
      fetchedMsg.delete();
    });
  }
});
```

How can I delete the message that the button was clicked on? (DM)

I can't find the channel of messages sent from dm.

Log:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fetch')
```

Comment: Can you telll us what happenned wrong exactly, if you have an error or if nothing happens etc..

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ButtonInteraction?scrollTo=channel), there is a [`interaction.channel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Interaction?scrollTo=channel) property available for you to use:

```js
if (custom_id && custom_id === "deletable") {
    const channel = interaction.channel;
    const fetchedMsg = await channel.messages.fetch({ around: interaction.message.id, limit: 1 });
    await fetchedMsg.delete();

    // Alternatively, you could also use this:
    await interaction.message.delete();  // :)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Over-complicated version: Get the message from `interaction` and use the `delete()` method to delete it

Simple/spoon-feeding version: `interaction.message.delete();`